# I can't fetch data from Sqlite using room result is 0

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, androidx

I have an application that uses room. I'm trying to get data from the database with this, but the result is 0. I have a record in db. I am debugging but ı cant see an error.What else should I control?

//Entity class
Apartment.class

```
@Entity(tableName = "Apartment")
public class Apartment {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int id;
@ColumnInfo(name = "barcode")
private String barcode;
@ColumnInfo(name = "image", typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.BLOB)
private byte[] image;
@ColumnInfo(name = "information")
private String information;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getBarcode() {
    return barcode;
}

public void setBarcode(String barcode) {
    this.barcode = barcode;
}

public byte[] getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(byte[] image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getInformation() {
    return information;
}

public void setInformation(String information) {
    this.information = information;
}
```

Dao class look like

```
ApartmentDao


@Dao
public interface ApartmentDAO {
String barcodeno=variable.barcode;
@Query("SELECT * FROM Apartment WHERE barcode LIKE '%' ||8681715340340||'%'")
List<Apartment> getwithbarcode();
```

AppDatabase class look like:

```
AppDatabase.class

 @Database(entities = {Apartment.class}, version = 1)
 public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
 public abstract ApartmentDAO apartmentDAO();

 }


 I called here look like
 MyActivity.class


 AppDatabase db=Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "RealEstateDb")
           .allowMainThreadQueries()
           .build();

  List<Apartment> apartment=db.apartmentDAO().getwithbarcode();
```

What am I doing wrong? Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: how data is inserted in database?

Comment: I dont insert .I'm trying to retrieve already existing data from the database I created with the Sqlite db browser.

Comment: are the column names exactly the same? and try a Cursor return type for testing that if query was successful